# How to convert decimal (28, 4) to another decimal with higher precision?

Tags: sql-server-2008, decimal

The problem is in data conversion from decimal (28, 4) to decimal (21,20). I am working on SQL Server 2008.

I have tried some snippets to solve my task, but as you see I cannot save data in decimal(21,20) because i get this message:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 35
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

Code:

```
UPDATE [table]  
SET [col] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(21, 20), [col1])
GO

ALTER TABLE [non_det_liabilities] 
    MODIFY [col1] DECIMAL(21, 20)
```

The result what i expecting is copied data with required decimal precision.

Comment: Are you aware that `DECIMAL(21,20)` in SQL Server means: 21 digits in all, **20** of which after the decimal point (leaving only a **single** digit before the decimal point)???? If your `decimal(28,4)` values have any values over 9.9999 - then the conversions will fail ..... you only have higher precision **after** the decimal point with your new datatype !

Comment: @marc_s I know that but i will put only percentages below 1.00 (0-100%).

Comment: And you are **150% sure** there are no values over 9.9999 in your original data? The error seems to indicate otherwise....

Comment: Also: as far as I know, T-SQL doesn't know a `MODIFY` command - you need to use `ALTER TABLE .... ALTER COLUMN col1 DECIMAL(21,20)` statement to achieve this

Comment: I used ALTER COLUMN... And i have error: "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: I told you once I have over there values below 1.00 :)  - Interest field

Comment: Ok, problem was on bad dataset - i had values bigger than 9.9999.. so @marc_s you got right. :) Thank you for your help.  :)